# How to use CloudFormation to edit a VPC's default network ACL?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, aws-cloudformation

If I declare the following resource in a CloudFormation template,

```
"CoolVpc": {
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC",
  "Properties": {
    "CidrBlock": "10.10.0.0/16",
    "Tags": [
      {"Key": "Name", "Value": "cool-vpc"},
    ]
  }
}
```

... CloudFormation will dutifully comply and create my VPC, and as part of the process it will automatically create a default network ACL to go along with it. I could easily *reference* that ACL using the `GetAtt` function, like:

```
"TestSubnetAcl": {
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::SubnetNetworkAclAssociation",
  "Properties": {
    "NetworkAclId": {"Fn::GetAtt" : ["CoolVpc" , "DefaultNetworkAcl"]},
    "SubnetId": {"Ref": "TestSubnet"}
  }
}
```

or

```
"AclRule100": {
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry",
  "Properties": {
    "CidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0",
    "Egress": "true",
    "Protocol": "-1",
    "RuleAction": "allow",
    "RuleNumber": "100",
    "NetworkAclId": {"Fn::GetAtt" : ["CoolVpc" , "DefaultNetworkAcl"]}
  }
}
```

... but what if I wanted to *edit* the default network ACL itself? (Yes, I know the only thing that can be changed there are the `Tags`, but that's exactly what I want to edit.)

I've tried adding a new NetworkAcl to the template and only using that, but the unnamed default keeps hanging around and it bugs me that I don't have a way to assign tags to it that make it clear what its purpose is.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this, as it's exactly what I want to do now.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer is : "you can't"

Cloud formation is designed to manage and maintain resources declared in the template.
Resources that are not part of the template cannot be changed/deleted.

As a consequence, you can add nACLs rule(s) in the default nACL, but with a RuleNumber that is not 100.

Rgds